# Display object contents - JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

With `$(this).data("events");` returning `[object Object]`, I need to see what's actually going on in there.  I found this:

```
var Finder = "";
$.each($(this).data("events"), function(i, n){
    Finder += "Name: " + i + ", Value: " + n + " | ";
});
```

However, `n` still returns `[object Object]`:

EDIT: (Output) --

```
Name: click, Value: [object Object] |
```

--

Is there an efficient way to show everything inside that sucker, kind of like `print_r` in PHP?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`console.log($(this).data("events"))` in Chrome (or other browsers) would allow you to drill into the object.

Ctrl+Shift+J gets you to the console in Chrome.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `.toSource()` to turn JavaScript objects into a string representation that you can view without a nice error console like in Firebug or Chrome Dev. Tools:

```
alert($(this).data("events").toSource());
```

Comment: I saw you had `toString()` in there before... Which was actually a better solution, since that will work on most browsers, where as `toSource()` will not work in IE.

Comment: I almost removed my answer because I can't explain the difference between `toString()` and `toSource()`. If anyone knows it'd be nice to have them chime in.

Comment: From what I understand, `toSource()` will convert the `object` into `JSON` formatting.  W3C: "The toSource() method represents the source code of an object." (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toSource_date.asp)  Seems like the `JSON` output is really the key here.

Answer (score 5):

If you can't use `console.log` then `alert( $(this).data("events").toSource() )` can also be used.

Answer (score 3):

Print content of object you can use

```
console.log(obj_str);
```

you can see the result in console like below.

```
Object {description: "test"}
```

For open console press F12 in chrome browser, you will found console tab in debug mode.