# Show jQuery (JS) objects' contents in Chrome Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Im getting my objects returned in the console as `[object Object]`, however which way I try to have it log all of the contents of the objects I get nothing or errors. I've read a whole lot of questions on SO about this (e.g.: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143386/display-object-contents-js-jquery), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974740/how-do-i-console-log-a-jquery-dom-element-in-chrome), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136989/chrome-can-no-longer-log-inspectable-jquery-objects-from-scripts), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832397/console-not-behaving-as-expected-when-logged-objects-change) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13974740/how-do-i-console-log-a-jquery-dom-element-in-chrome)) but still can't figure it out.

I've created some objects by looping through JSON array's using:

```
var tables = {};

$.each(campaigns, function(key, value){
    tables[value] = '';
    var entries = [];
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        if(v.campaign == value){
            entries.push(v);
        }
    });
    $.extend(tables[value], entries);
});

console.log('tables: ' + tables);
```

The amount of objects is correct based on the number of objects returned with different conditions and parameters. However, I would like to see *what's actually inside them*! I don't want to include all sorts of external scripts, do weird and unnecessary loopy-loops, just some simple command I'm overlooking would be awesome!

How to go about logging objects with something like `console.log(someObj);`?

Comment: Is `console.log('tables: ', tables)` working better? Don't force a toString() on the object, the console should give you a nice object browser.

Comment: Yep! Got the answer already. ;)  I've been ridiculously stupid and have been mixing the `+` and `,` in the `console.log('bla', blop)` vs the `console.log('bla' + blop)` for weeks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
console.log('tables: ' + JSON.stringify(tables));
```

or in FF and Chrome

```
console.log('tables: ', tables);
```

Comment: Oh very nice, straight away get to see what's in the tables, and noticing some errors in my code already! :) Thanks a lot! The edit to your answer though: "or in FF and Chrome `console.log('tables: ', tables)`... I've been mixing up the `+` and `,` for weeks now! UGH!!! **facepalm**

Answer (score 0):

If it is a HTML object, then you can see the value with $(tables).text()

Answer (score 0):

Use console.table for tabular data.

```
console.table(tables);
```